# Unix directory deletion:

Tags: linux, rm

There was a directory structure on my linux server like this `A/$b/`
From my home directory executed a command

```
rm -rf A/$b.
```

After executing this command, The directory A itself was deleted.

Any idea what would have happened in the background?

Answer (score 1):

A `$` sign indicates the start of a variable in most shell languages.

If `$b` is not defined then your command would resolve as:

```
rm -rf A/
```

… which would delete the A directory.

To include the `$` in the path you need to escape it:

```
rm -rf A/\$B
```